# How can i save videos from watsup to the phone memory of nokia lumia 520

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, nokia, windows-phone-8-emulator

How can i save videos from **watsup** to the phone memory of **nokia lumia 520**?

Comment: Do you mean whatsapp?

Comment: yes whatsapp application

Comment: Is it possible or not? because there is no option there to save videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats app still does not expose the videos for saving. You can view it from with the app.

Here's a discussion forum i picked up from wpcentral

[Video Cannot be saved Whats app](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-720/229463-whatsapp-videos-download.html)

Sorry for the Info but I dont think there a crack to this.

Comment: okay.. If the user who shared that video deletes from his chat then its not possible to view that from the phone.

Comment: we have an option for android and ios but for wp i dont think theres a possibility http://www.mymagicmix.com/how-to-get-back-deleted-whatsapp-messages-photos-videos/

Comment: Regarding your second question. I am exactly a WP Developer but Dont have whats app. Sorry for that :(